# Pre/post/in -order write to txt file ( 3 txt file)

Tags: c++

i'm working on ubuntu64 bit ( c++) 
I have a binary tree and the code working well.. but  i need create 3 txt file ( preorder.txt,inorder.txt,postorder.txt) with the numbers..When i'M running my code i got everything but just in terminal.. and i dont know how write this 3 thing to txt file.Thank you for readed my drama..

[image: this is what i see after running my code]

but i copy here too the terminal :

> vilmos@ubuntu:~$ g++ binfa1.cpp 
>   vilmos@ubuntu:~$ ./a.out
>   10,5,6,8,11,14,18,
>    preorder
>   5,6,8,10,11,14,18,
>    inorder
>   5,6,8,11,14,18,10,
>    postorder

---

So i need :

> 1. preorder.txt
> 2. inorder.txt
> 3. postorder.txt

*with the numbers aswell*

**this is my first   question..and sorry for bad english**

Comment: If I could only see your code ...  On the other hand, I would guess that your pre-, in-, and post- order functions all simply use std::cout.  Consider adding a parameter to each function to specify where to output.

Comment: i see so many void  :/  i'm working with this code : https://gist.github.com/toboqus/def6a6915e4abd66e922

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Answer (score 0):

> but i need create 3 txt file ( preorder.txt,inorder.txt,postorder.txt)
>   with the numbers

So, that code you pointed to has, as one example:

```
void btree::inorder_print(){
    inorder_print(root);
    cout << "\n";
}

void btree::inorder_print(node *leaf){
    if(leaf != NULL){
        inorder_print(leaf->left);
        cout << leaf->value << ",";
        inorder_print(leaf->right);
    }
}
```

Just as I had guessed, the functions use cout so all the output goes to the std output, which often defaults to the user screen.

---

Now consider this light modification:

```
void btree::inorder_print(std::ostream& ostrm = std::cout){
    inorder_print(root, ostrm);
    ostrm << "\n";
}

void btree::inorder_print(node *leaf, std::ostream& ostrm = std::cout){
    if(leaf != NULL){
        inorder_print(leaf->left, ostrm);
        ostrm << leaf->value << ",";
        inorder_print(leaf->right, ostrm);
    }
}
```

Your existing code will work as before, because cout is entered as a default parameter, and cout is a std::ostream.

To change where the output goes, you simply open an ostream to your desired path, and pass that to these functions.  Don't forget to close.

---

Overview:  The 'working' code is modified to accept a destination (that defaults to cout).